# Remote Desktop on Linux cooperating with Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, software-rec, remote-desktop

Which Linux remote desktop servers cooperate also with Windows Clients, so I can log onto my machine from Windows standard program and Ubuntu one?

Systems: Natty Narwhal and Windows XP, Vista, 7